# How to programmatically apply DataTemplate to View Model class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

In my WPF Application I have `MainWindow` control, and `GraphControl` user control placed inside Window by XAML markup. `GraphControl` has assigned `GraphControlViewModel`, and it contains accessory `GraphView` control (derived from `Control` class). The outline (simplified) of implementations of that types is following:

**GraphControl.xaml**:

```
<UserControl
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:designer="clr-namespace:Designer"
  xmlns:GraphUI="clr-namespace:GraphUI;assembly=GraphUI"
  xmlns:GraphModel="clr-namespace:GraphModel;assembly=GraphModel">

  /* simplified document content */

  <UserControl.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type GraphModel:NodeViewModel}">

          /* data template definition here*/

      </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>

  </UserControl.Resources>

  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <designer:GraphControlViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <DockPanel>

    <GraphUI:GraphView NodesSource="{Binding Graph.Nodes}" />

  </DockPanel>

</UserControl>
```

**GraphControlViewModel.cs:**

```
public class GraphControlViewModel : AbstractModelBase
{
    private GraphViewModel graph;

    public GraphViewModel Graph
    {
        get
        {
            return this.graph;
        }
        set
        {
            this.graph = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("Graph");
        }
    }

    // implementation here
}
```

**GraphViewModel.cs:**

```
public sealed class GraphViewModel
{
    private ImpObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> nodes;

    public ImpObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nodes ?? ( this.nodes = new ImpObservableCollection<NodeViewModel>() );
        }
    }

    // implementation here
}
```

**NodeViewModel.cs:**

```
public sealed class NodeViewModel : AbstractModelBase
{
   // implementation here
}
```

**GraphView.cs:**

```
public partial class GraphView : Control
{
    // implementation of display details here

    public IEnumerable NodesSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)this.GetValue(NodesSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(NodesSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Application works and looks as it was invented, `DataTemplate` is properly applied to View Model class.

However, at this moment, there is need to add `x:key` attribute to `DataTemplate` definition, for accessibility purposes:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NodeViewModelKey" DataType="{x:Type GraphModel:NodeViewModel}">

    /* data template definition here*/

</DataTemplate>
```

And here my problem occurs. As it is stated in [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) documentation on MSDN:

`If you assign this DataTemplate an x:Key value, you are overriding the implicit x:Key and the DataTemplate would not be applied automatically.`

Indeed, after I add `x:Key` attribute, `DataTemplate` is not applied to my View Model class.

How can I programmatically apply DataTemplate in my case?

Comment: @Omribitan, really? That's the opposite of MVVM best practice. The model should not be exposed directly to the UI - that's what the ViewModel is for.

Comment: @MarkGreen YOU ARE RIGHT! got confused, took it back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name your `GraphView` like:

```
<GraphUI:GraphView x:Name="myGraph" NodesSource="{Binding Graph.Nodes}" />
```

In the code behind of your usercontrol you can do:

```
      myGraph.Resources.Add(
      new DataTemplateKey(typeof(NodeViewModel)), 
      Resources["NodeViewModelKey"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add a `DataTemplate` dependency property to the `GraphView`, and then try to use it something like this :

```
<GraphUI:GraphView NodesSource="{Binding Graph.Nodes}" 
                   DataTemplate={StaticResource NodeViewModelKey}/>
```